# When to create an array in memory and when to create in storage in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, solidity-0.8.x

I was learning about arrays in Solidity .
I am not getting exactly when should I create an array in memory and when in storage .
So far I only know that an array created in memory is fixed in size and I cannot use push and pop methods in that case .

Can anyone explain the difference between an array created in memory ( what it is , how it behaves , gas costs etc . ) and an array created in storage ?

Reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTxxCbwMPwo

Answer (score 1):

The main differences are:

1. Storage, persistent contract state, costly
2. Memory, transient, fixed length only, cheaper

Generally, use storage to record things and memory as a scratch pad.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Rob , " Generally, use storage to record things and memory as a scratch pad. " 
Can you explain this line a bit more ?

Comment: Well, memory is cheaper but it is erased after txn finishes. Storage is more like a database. It will last but i/o is more expensive.